# SQLAlchemy query marks id as null

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy to insert a row into a table. The table is defined like this:

```
class MyTable():
    __table__ = "my_table"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    stuff1 = Column(Numeric)
```

Here's the alchemy line:

```
MyTable(stuff1=100)
```

Here's the query it generates:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, stuff1) VALUES (null, 100)
```

And i get this error:

```
IntegrityError('(psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column \"id\" violates not-null constraint
```

Since the id is the primary key, i expected it to get generated automatically. But it seems like i have to manually apply a sequence to it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me before and usually I either didn't use sqlalchemy to create the table or my table definition in sqlalchemy was incomplete/incorrect when I did.  If you have a 'create table if not exists' setup then your changes won't be synchronized with the table definition in postgres.  I would checkout the table definition with the psql command line tool to verify if a server default is not setup for the primary key.  It should be a serial data type or using an external sequence.

Comment: Turns out i needed a SEQUENCE argument in the primary key column constructor